# Jmeter log active threads

Tags: logging, jmeter

I'm trying to get the number of active threads in the jmeter log, I've enabled it in the *jmeter.properties* file ad in the GUI option, what I've seen is that in the xml generated it adds two attributes, but I can't understand what they are.
Is there someone that can explain me?

```
<httpSample t="11946" ts="1342783786014" s="true" lb="Search Return" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="Test 1-17" dt="text" ng="11" na="11">
    <java.net.URL>http://mysite/search/</java.net.URL>
</httpSample>
```

This is what I have and the parameters added are: *ng* and *na*

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe before ask to people it is better to search deep in documentation...
here it is the solution:

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#attributes

```
na   Number of active threads for all thread groups
ng   Number of active threads in this group
```